# Matlab importdata function with custom output variable name

Tags: matlab, import, eval

I need to import data from a file whose path is stored in a variable named `fpath` and the output variable needs to have a name which is stored in another variable named `vname`. 
I was trying to use `eval` function, but got no success.
I used `eval([vname  '= importdata(fpath);']);`
 I am getting an error - `Unexpected MATLAB expression`.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a file /tmp/file.txt which contains 1234567890:

```
>> fpath = '/tmp/file.txt';
>> vname = 'foo';
>> eval(strcat(vname,'=importdata(''',fpath,''')'));

foo =

   1.2346e+09
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only need

```
vname = importdata(fpath);
```

No need for an eval statement. Vname should contain a matrix with your data.

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to answer without the full error message and not knowing the type and value of your `fpath` and `vname` variables. Evaluating `eval([vname '= dir(fpath);'])` with some generic variable name and path works fine for me.

That being said, I'd highly recommend against using `eval`. It's difficult to get the appropriate syntax, difficult to debug, and makes it difficult for MATLAB to optimize in the background. The first step to that is to evaluate (hah) why you're utilizing `eval` in the first place. If you're dynamically generating variable names I'd recommend utilizing a structure's ability to accept [dynamic field names](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/08/20/advanced-matlab-dynamic-field-names/) instead of resorting to `eval`.

For example:

```
vname = 'myvariable';
fpath = 'C:\test';
counter = 3;
mydata.([vname '_' num2str(counter)]) = dir(fpath);
```

Returns:

```
mydata = 

    myvariable_3: [21x1 struct]
```